# xcdatamodel with a new attribute

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite, core-data

I've updated the xcdatamodel with a new attribute. i've made sure to remake the managed object class file. the add new version/set current version has been done also.

I made sure to delete the app from the iPhone and even did the build > Clean all targets thing.

the problem is that when I look in the sqlite file the new attribute/field is not there.

how do I update the sqlite file so the new attribute is there?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQLite backing store for Core Data is to be treated as opaque — that is, the structure of the db is private to Core Data and it doesn't matter to you what it looks like.

So maybe you don't see it, but so long as Core Data itself can create objects with the new attribute you've added, that's all that matters.

Pretend the backing store database is gibberish.

Comment: I just realized that I can replace my sqlite file in xcode w/ the sqlite file from the iphone simulator and the new attribute/field is there like you were saying. 
I've been adding data directly to the sqlite file access to that new attribute from there.

thanks for your post.